# Prove that if $n$ is even, then there is a graph with $n$ vertices and $n^2/4$ edges that contains no $K_3$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Prove that if $n$ is even, then there is a graph with $n$ vertices and $n^2/4$ edges that contains no $K_3$.

Not sure how to approach this one.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n's_theorem for a more general statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a graph that is triangle-free, and bipartite graphs are often a good place to start. In this case the complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$ fulfills the requirements.